# Is there any jutsu that Naruto won't be able to master without the Kyuubi?

Tags: naruto

I'm just curious if there is any jutsu that would be impossible for Naruto to learn or master without the powers of the Kyuubi inside him?

If there is, which is it and why won't he be able to learn/master it without the Kyuubi? If there's none, then I guess Naruto is actually a smart ninja.

Comment: Hmmm.. Obviously the [The Nine-Tails Chakra Mode](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki's_Jinch%C5%ABriki_Forms)

Comment: @ChristianMark, care to answer it and include explanation? I haven't watch Naruto for a long time so I was just curious. ;P

Comment: Actually the Nine-tails chakra is just a prerequisite of the Bijuu Ball Blast.

Comment: My votes goes to most of the [Kekkei Genkai](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kekkei_Genkai) jutsu's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here are some of the jutsu Naruto probably can't (or will be near impossible) to learn without Kurama:

- Techniques from elements other than Wind - Naruto's natural chakra affinity is towards wind, while he can train in other elements, he probably won't be able to learn some of the other elements. (Actually has nothing to do with the Bijuu, that's kinda what happens to everyone)
- The Bijuu Dama - a Bijuu specific technique (the nuclear-warhead like black sphere).
- It's possible that using Kurama's Yang element chakra (sealed within Naruto), he'll be able to do *something*.
- Tajuu Kage Bunshin - Even though Naruto naturally has massive chakra reserves, he wouldn't be able to make as much copies without the Kyuubi Chakra Pool.

Comment: If Naruto did not have the Kyubi in him, I doubt he would even be alive. He would have died during the battle with Gaara(during Chunin exams), let alone master jutsus..

Comment: The entire story line would be changed if Naruto didn't have the nine tails. It's possible that he would never have met Gaara.

Answer (score 0):

Naruto was able to do multiple shadow clones (thousands of shadow clones) WITHOUT KURAMA or any other natural energy source. This is when he stopped taking karuma's help (Ep 52) and started learning rasenshuriken on his own. I guess most of the guys are getting it wrong here. I understand that kyuubi is the main reason behind his healing but you can't forget the uzumaki clan healing abilities and the level of chakra they possess. Naruto was able to maintain clones without kurama chakra and yamato was there to stop going kurama mode when naruto's chakra is completely depleted. I guess without kurama, Naruto can always learn different jutsus using multiple shadow clones with his OWN massive chakra level (20 years of training in just a week). LETS GIVE NARUTO A LITTLE CREDIT HERE!!

Comment: I don't think it's stated anywhere that *all* Uzumaki Clan members have extraordinary healing powers...  All thats really mentioned is that they have large chakra and are skilled in Fuinjutsu.

Answer (score -1):

most of naruto jutsu really on bijuu.
even the rasenshuriken (his only futon jutsu), without kyuubi heal ability, naruto arm would be disabled to cell level after the first try.
If naruto hadn't kyuubi power (strong seal, fully isolate kyuubi from naruto like a high secured living storage scroll) naruto would be a outcast nobody (his strong own chakra level come from the seal convert and mix kyuubi chakra with his own)

Comment: The Nine-Tails really had no role in making sure Naruto's arm wasn't damaged when using the Rasen-Shuriken. It's the fact that upon activating Sage Mode, he could throw it.